# Effect of lights off / lights on on HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, effect, light

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate the lights off / lights on effect on a website. When a button is clicked the website would go dark (whatever darkness could be simulated as...) or just turn on the lights and the website would be visible again. I am really blank on the matter... I am not sure if this could be done by just changing the website element colours in a very specific way or with some type of effects library, canvas... I really have no idea.

Can someone clarify me? Sorry for mistakes, I am new to the matter

Comment: What? It's unclear what you're asking. Are you wondering if you can change the colour of a page at the press of a button, or if you can simulate the viewers light conditions on a page?

Comment: Simulate the viewers light conditions on a page. If I had landscape background for example a way to see it as you would see with daylight and at night

Comment: You can use [ambient light](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Ambient_Light_Events) to figure out if it's dark or bright where the person is sitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic solution that turns your theme to dark/bright.

The best i can thing of is css `html.inverse *, html.inverse { filter: invers(); }` but even that don't work nicely.
Another is just a dark div overlay with opacity and css click through. You are probably best of creating two different stylesheet (some css preprocessor has darker/brighter mixin and variables that you can use to help you build different stylesheet)

if you still insist with some magical solution that works for every site/css then maybe https://www.turnoffthelights.com is something for you. they also have a bookmarklet that tries to do magic the best it can

Otherwise this question is just to broad...